# Splitting a beamer page into minipages by horizontal and vertical splits, and using "pause" to display minipages one-by-one

Tags: beamer, minipage, pause

I want to split a page into 3 minipages (sections): 2 minipages in the left half of the page (by splitting the left half horizontally) and 1 minipage in the right half of the page. In each minipage, I want a figure and a footnote or text to be inserted. The MWE using the `minipage` environment is given below. This only shows the "Figure left top" and "Figure right." "Figure left bottom" does not appear. Also, "Figure right" is displayed on the left bottom section. I also would like to display these minipages one-by-one, by using `pause` which has been commented right now. Please suggest what's going wrong here, and if `minipage` is not the best way to achieve this. Is that because I haven't specified the positions correctly for each of the three minipages?

```
\begin{frame}{Title of frame}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}
%       \begin{figure}
%           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_left_top.pdf}
%       \end{figure}
        \footnotetext{Figure left top}
    \end{minipage}
    %\pause
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.9\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}
%       \begin{figure}
%           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_right.pdf}
%       \end{figure}
        \footnotetext{Figure right}
    \end{minipage}
    %\pause
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}
%       \begin{figure}
%           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_left_bottom.pdf}
%       \end{figure}
        \footnotetext{Figure left bottom}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The "problem" with your example is, that the second minipage has a height of 90% of the available space. In the next line, only 10% are still available, which is not enough to see your third image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for a layout like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title of frame}
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                \begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                \end{figure}
                \footnotetext{Figure left top}
            \end{minipage}  
            \begin{onlyenv}<3>
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
                    \end{figure}
                \footnotetext{Figure left bottom}
                \end{minipage}
            \end{onlyenv}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{onlyenv}<2->
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=.77\textheight]{example-image}
                    \end{figure}
                    \footnotetext{Figure right}
                \end{minipage}
            \end{onlyenv}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the layout that I want. However, I would also like to know if the same can be achieved with minipage only, without using columns. The second image was supposed to occupy the whole right side (90% of the height), which is why the second minipage was given '0.9\textheight.' Hope you got the idea.

Comment: By the way thank you very much for your help, @samcarter!

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli To give the right hand image the possibility to occupy the whole height was the reason I used columns. With minipages alone this will be very difficult, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343270/splitting-a-beamer-page-into-minipages-by-horizontal-and-vertical-splits-and-us/343273?noredirect=1#comment842503_343270

Comment: thanks, I understand. But the link that you gave points to this same page, why so?

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli The link points to a specific comment on this site, in which I tried to explain, why minipages alone won't work for your problem.